# How to change the background color that appears at top when we pull down a website on mobile device?

Tags: custom-background

The website is https://samanthayardley.com/

[image]

In the top there is a bluish rectangle, that comes when we pull the site down to refresh. How can that color be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply the background colour of the `body` element. On your site it's currently set as this:

```
body {
    background-color: #c1e7e7;
}
```

This appears to be being added by your theme, probably based on a customisation option somewhere. You'd be able to overwrite it by adding matching CSS in *Appearance > Customize > Addition CSS*, if you can't find it.

Comment: Thank you very much.